# iOS Handle Push notifications on application startup only when UI is ready

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

When the application is **not** running, and a notification is received, it will arrive inside:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool
```

I have a log there and all is fine, however, let's say I want to show an alert with the body of the notification?

My alert code uses `window!.rootViewController?.presentViewController()`, however inside `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` the UI has not loaded yet, and there is not view controller yet.

What is the best practice to trigger UI events in this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

You have different options on the base of your architecture and view controllers flow. For example you can have a kind of `NotificationManager`, a singleton which has the responsibility to store information about any push notification received.
In your `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` you can set the notification in such manager; afterwards the first view controller you present could interrogate such manager and decide whether there is any notification to consume or continue with the normal flow.

Hope it helps.